# Does Profile Manager support nested device groups?

Tags: osx-server, server.app, profile-manager, configuration-profiles

We have a Mac OS X Server running on 10.10.5 with Server 5.0.15. We are using Profile Manager to deploy some basic configuration settings.

There are five Macs besides the server: three MacBook Pros, two Mac Minis. I set up the following device groups:

Desktop Macs
Mobile Macs
Company Macs

The three MacBook Pros are in the Mobile Macs group, the two mac Minis are in the Desktop Macs group. Company Macs has the other two groups as its members.

However, it seems that the settings for Company Macs are not being propagated to the clients. Activity for the group shows "Push Settings: Succeeded"… but it shows that even for a client machine that has been powered off since before I made the settings change. My other machines do not show any Profiles for the Company Macs group, only the specific group they are assigned to.

Even more curious: when I remove the nested groups, and simply assign the laptops to Mobile Macs and Company Macs group explicitly, the Company Macs profile is *still* not pushed out.

Should this work with nested device groups? I don't want to wipe Profile Manager and start over if it's not intended to work this way (but then why is it even an option to add a group to another group?). My hunch is that something is corrupt with the Company Macs group, since it's not pushing the profile even for Macs manually assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.**

The problem was that a process on the server or the client did not like one of the settings payloads in the "outer" group (Directory in my case).